# Applications Keep Jumping to the Top of the Page on MacBook

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, display, applications

Frequently while clicking on non-apple applications on my mackbook the pages jump to the top. It always happens when switching from one application to another. I have been trying to find a solution for a while now, with no luck. Help would be incredibly appreciated :)

Some applications that it happens in currently: Brave Browser, Chrome, Microsoft Word, Notion and multiple other apps. I have a 2021 MacBook Pro with Monterey v12.5.

Below is a video of the issue happening in Notion.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q6ufT7FyW7tkouHUMnKEe_4xhpz9KnHQ/view?usp=sharing